# jQuery: If all children have same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if all children, or all selectors, have same class?

The class is unknown...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var symbols = $("div:first-child").attr("class");

        if ($("div").hasClass(symbols).length == 3) {
            console.log("same");
        };
    });
</script>
<div class="john"></div>
<div class="john"></div>
<div class="john"></div>
```

This doesn't work... :-/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$("div").not('.john').length
```

If any of the divs are not class john this will find them, then you check the length and if it's not zero then some exist.

This is a problem:

```
$("div:first-child").attr("class")
```

It will return the entire class string, but the div could have more than one class, and all will be returned. But when you check with either my code or `hasClass` you can only send in one class, not a bunch together.

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<div class="parent"> 
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($(".parent").children().length == $(".parent").children(".child").length) {
    alert("wooo all the things have teh same class");
}
```

Comment: Just make a string like .children("."+className) instead of ".child" ;)